# How to update user on node backend with supabase Auth

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, supabase

I want to udate the user on the backend where all of the authentication takes place
After the i recive the resetpassword email, i want to use the token sent in the URL and sign in the user then upate the password

```
export const resetPassword = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  try {
    await updatePasswordYupSchema.validate(req.body, {
      abortEarly: false,
    });
    const { data, error } = await supabaseClient.auth.updateUser({
      password: req.body.password,
    });
    if (error) throw error;
    res.status(200).json({ success: data });
  } catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof ValidationError) {
      const errorObject = yupError(err);
      next(errorObject);
    } else if (
      err instanceof AuthApiError ||
      err instanceof AuthSessionMissingError
    ) {
      console.log(err);
      customErrorHandler(err.status, err.message, res);
    } else {
      next(err);
    }
  }
};
```

**I am getting this error `Auth session missing!`**

I tried using `await supabaseClient.auth.getSession()` but the session returned is null

`{ data: { session: null }, error: null }`

I also tried to get the user with the JWT token `await supabaseClient.auth.getUser(req.headers.authorization)` but there is not seeion object on it

```
{
  data: {
    user: {
      id: 'aa8c4b73-ba8d-4901-a768-1b48b72e334c',
      ...
    }
  },
  error: null
}
```

Comment: Is the user signed in on the client side?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? The client only receives an Auth Token, which is received on the server from supabase.